# Uncaught TypeError creating an Aurelia Plugin: plugin.load is not a function

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I created a new `Aurelia` plugin, which is named `Aurelia-Slickgrid` and got it all working locally with `.feature('resources')`. I was then ready for the next step, making it available to everyone as a plugin and created a Github project and made it available under this [GitHub link - Aurelia-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/aurelia-slickgrid). I used [Aurelia Skeleton Plugin](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-plugin) to create my plugin, also ran `gulp build` to create the transpiled output. I then published it on `NPM` and successfully installed it with `npm i --save aurelia-slickgrid`. I am currently using `Aurelia-CLI` to bundle and everything goes well, until I open the browser and see that an error got thrown in the console (now I'm left with a white page in the browser):

```
Uncaught TypeError: plugin.load is not a function
    at Module.<anonymous> (vendor-bundle.js:5308)
    ...
```

For the moment, I am trying to load it as a plugin with `Aurelia-CLI`. See below for the complete configuration used:

`index.js` of the plugin

```
import {AureliaSlickgrid} from './aurelia-slickgrid';
import {SlickPager} from './slick-pager';
import {SlickWindowResizer} from './slick-window-resizer';

export function configure(config) {
  config.globalResources('./aurelia-slickgrid');
  config.globalResources('./slick-pager');
  config.globalResources('./slick-window-resizer');
}

export {
  AureliaSlickgrid,
  SlickPager,
  SlickWindowResizer
}
```

`main.js` (of my local project)

```
aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .feature('resources')
    .plugin('aurelia-slickgrid');
```

`aurelia.json` (of my local project)

```
{
     "name": "aurelia-slickgrid",
     "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-slickgrid/dist/amd",
     "main": "index"
},
```

If you're testing with an empty Aurelia CLI project you need to add:

```
      {
        "name": "aurelia-slickgrid",
        "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-slickgrid/dist/amd",
        "main": "index"
      },
      "slickgrid-es6",
      "jquery"
```

Finally `import` to use it in code via:

```
import {AureliaSlickgrid} from 'aurelia-slickgrid';
```

The documentation on how to create an `Aurelia Plugin` is almost non existing, so I based myself on another plugin, namely [Aurelia-Bootstrap](https://github.com/tochoromero/aurelia-bootstrap) made by a great Aurelia Contributor. One of the file that greatly influenced my plugin code was his [index.js](https://github.com/tochoromero/aurelia-bootstrap/blob/master/src/index.js) and I used his coding styling to code mine.

Any idea where could be my problem?

---

I also tried to add `resources` to the `aurelia.json`, however it had no effects.

```
{
  "name": "aurelia-slickgrid",
  "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-slickgrid/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.html"
  ]
},
```

---

Got a bit further, after searching for a few other Aurelia plugins. It seems that `globalResources` should only be View/ViewModel pair (html/js), in my case I only have 1 of those pair which is `SlickPager` and now only that one is being called by `globalResources()`. Another possible problem, still to confirm though, I had a file named `aurelia-slickgrid.js` which is the same naming as the plugin name, could that cause a conflict? Possibly...who knows. So anyway, I renamed it to `slick-service.js` and renamed the class to `SlickService`. I am now able to call 2/3 of my objects in the `WebPack Skeleton`, however I still can't import `SlickService`.

updated `index.js` of the plugin

```
import { SlickService } from './slick-service';
import { SlickPager } from './slick-pager';
import { SlickWindowResizer } from './slick-window-resizer';

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.globalResources('./slick-pager');
}

export { SlickService, SlickPager, SlickWindowResizer };
```

I can now call this in `WebPack` without issues

```
import {SlickPager, SlickWindowResizer} from 'aurelia-slickgrid';
@inject(SlickPager, SlickWindowResizer)

export class Test {
  constructor(slickPager, slickWindowResizer) {
    console.log(slickPager, slickWindowResizer);
  }
}
```

However if I import `SlickService` as well, it throws an error

```
import {SlickPager, SlickWindowResizer, SlickService} from 'aurelia-slickgrid';
@inject(SlickPager, SlickWindowResizer, SlickService)

export class Test {
   constructor(slickPager, slickWindowResizer, slickService) {
      console.log(slickPager, slickWindowResizer, slickService);
   }
}
```

previous code with `SlickService` now throws this error

```
ERROR [app-router] Error: Error invoking SlickService. Check the inner error for details.
------------------------------------------------
Inner Error:
Message: key/value cannot be null or undefined. Are you trying to inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?
```

Comment: Perhaps you are missing to load the HTML files? `"resources": ["**/*.html"]` after your `"main": "index"` entry.

Comment: One minor issue with the code: [this](https://github.com/ghiscoding/aurelia-slickgrid/blob/master/src/slick-pager.js#L2) should be `jquery` instead of `bootstrap`.
I wonder if this is a bug with the aurelia-cli. Have you tried using the plugin in one of the skeleton projects?

Comment: @MarcScheib I forgot to mention that I already tried to add 'resources' with `**/*.html` and no differences. @JeremyDanyow I changed the jquery reference and re-published a version and that doesn't fix the issue (also note that it was all working locally). I only tried `Aurelia-CLI` because I don't know how to load `SASS` in `Aurelia-Webpack` which my plugin uses

Comment: I've had difficulty creating my first Aurelia plugin as well. I posted on stack overflow and didn't get the issue resolved. There really needs to be documentation and a step-by-step guide. Plugins are big since they allow the community to easily share. Making plugin development easier should be a top priority.

Comment: Got a bit further, but still not out of the wood. Can someone confirm that in `globalResources()` call, it should only be View/ViewModel pair? Also, does it matter if a js file is named exactly like the plugin name (in my case `aurelia-slickgrid.js`)?

Comment: in `slick-window-resizer.js` you're exporting `SlickWindowResizer` but importing `SlickResizer` in `slick-service.js`, hence the null or undefined inject error

Comment: Thanks @noj, that was it. Your answer and RabahG answer help me fix it. I can finally sleep :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It doesn't matter if you call your file the same as your plugin.
2. globalResources accepts not only view/vm pairs but (.html for html-only components and single file resources like custom attributes binding behaviors and value converters).
3. you have a typo in slick-service.js you should be importing SlickWindowResizer not SlickResizer.
4. in aurelia.json you need to add the resources array, like: `"resources": ["**/*.{css,html}"]`

Comment: Yes this is it, I finally got it working thanks to @noj and yourself. Your point 4 also helped me get going with `Aurelia-CLI` as well, and I also didn't know you could write it on 1 line to get all `css` and `html` which is awesome. This is awesome :)

Comment: This kind of information should really be part of `Aurelia Plugin` documentation... the problem is that the doc doesn't exist :(